# Spring RestTemplate receives "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am using the following to retrieve JSON via RestTemplate in Spring 4:

```
protected DocInfoResponse retrieveData(String urlWithAuth) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth.getSig());
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<DocInfoResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlWithAuth, HttpMethod.GET, request, DocInfoResponse.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

I used the same code (with different response class) to successfully get a JSON doc from the same site (with different parameters to get a different doc).

When I execute the above code I receive the following stack trace (in part):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized 
at 
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone point me to why this might be receiving the exception?

Comment: Have you tried to access the same from browser or postman? Is it working there with this authentication?

Comment: Yes, I have gotten the same URL to successfully return expected results in browsers.

Comment: It surely is an authentication problem. Are you generating digital signatures for authentication? Is the signature URL specific?

Comment: Digital signature is being generated. That is in the 'auth.getSig()' call. There is nothing in the site documentation that specifies it is URL specific. The same signature/algorithm is used in both cases (the URL that works and the one that doesn't).

Comment: Can you share the other method which is working?

Comment: It is exactly the same, with the following two exceptions: 1) the URL, 2) the response object (SyncResponse.class vs DocInfoResponse.class -- the former is working, the latter is the problem).

Comment: Some digital signatures are URL specific. That being said resttemplate encodes the URL making it a bit difficult when you have a digital signature which most of the times is specifc to the URL. I am not sure how `auth.getSig()` generated a digital signature as in most of the cases it is validated against the client information provided in the URL

Comment: Hi I'm having the exact same problem. I am able to connect to the target URL using FireFox RESTClient in Basic Authentication. However, I'm getting a "401 Unauthorized" while usint Spring RestTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that my issue originally posted above was due to double encryption happening on the `auth` params. I resolved it by using `UriComponentsBuilder` and explicitly calling `encode()` on the  the `exchange()`.

```
SyncResponse retrieveData(UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<SyncResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, request, SyncResponse.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

My `UriComponentsBuilder` was built using:

```
UriComponentsBuilder buildUrl(String urlString) {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlString);

    return auth.appendAuth(builder);
}
```

(The `auth.appendAuth()` adds additional `.queryParams()` needed by the target service in `urlString`.)

The call to execute this was `retrieveData(buildUrl(urlString));`.

Comment: I have a similar issue but I cannot fix it. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843944/spring-boot-microservices-rest-template-401-unauthorized-error

Answer (score 0):

After investigating on my own problem, I realized that FireFox RESTClient was successful because I was connected to the target URL. The Basic Auth I thought I was using, was not so basic after all.

Eventually, I read the doc of the app i was trying to connect to and realized they propose a connection token mechanism. Now it works.

After reading your code, I say it looks quite OK, although I'm not sure what is your object `auth` on which you call `getSig`.

First things first: try to access your service from any client, like a web browser, a PostMan or RESTClient. Make sure you successfully retrieve your infos WITHOUT being connected to your app!!!

Depending on the result, I say you should, either try to encrypt manually your `Authorization` token (you'll easilly find posts on this site to show you how to) or try another connection mechanism.

Comment: In my case, the authorization string was being double encrypted.

I resolved this by doing something similar to your suggestion of manual encryption ... using 'UriComponentsBuilder'.

Comment: glad this helped! your question was helpful too :)

Answer (score 0):

The process of creating the Authorization header is relatively straightforward for Basic Authentication, so it can pretty much be done manually with a few lines of code:

```
 HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password){
   return new HttpHeaders() {{
         String auth = username + ":" + password;
         byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( 
            auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
         String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
         set( "Authorization", authHeader );
      }};
}
```

Then, sending a request becomes just as simple:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
restTemplate.exchange
     (uri, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<T>(createHeaders(username, password)), clazz);
```

https://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring#manual_auth